# Using WCF Service on web host server

Tags: asp.net, web-services, wcf, soap

The possibility of this being a duplicate question is high. 
The reason I'm querying it again, is that I have searched through tons of articles to no avail. I need some guidance, perhaps it may be specific to my application.

I've written a WCF Service, which works fine on the localhost. 
Once the website is published to the live hosting server,
* I cannot access the WSDL - I obtain a 404 - File or directory not found. 
* Should I try an add a service reference to the application, I get:

```
There was an error downloading 'http://freewaytoyota.co.za/FreewayToyotaService.svc/$metadata'.
The request failed with HTTP status 403: ModSecurity Action.
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://freewaytoyota.co.za/FreewayToyotaService.svc'.
The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'.
The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.
```

My web.config is as follows:

```
 <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IFreewayToyotaService" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
    <endpoint address="http://localhost:8777/FreewayToyotaService.svc"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IFreewayToyotaService"
        contract="FreewayServiceReference.IFreewayToyotaService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IFreewayToyotaService" />
    </client>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" minFreeMemoryPercentageToActivateService="1"/>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

I have not made any changes. This is the original file.
How do I modify it to get the .svc working on the live web host server.
Please help :(. Thanks in advance.

Comment: according to the error message the URL you are using to add the service reference is not valid, you've got the protocol twice

Comment: My bad. Wrong Error. Changed.

Comment: Did you try turning on anonymous authentication for the web application?   Also, you don't need to specify an endpoint address if the service is hosted in IIS (as a general rule).  Note that in the endpoint you've specified you're also setting a port, but there is no port in the URL you're using to get the metadata.

Comment: I havent tried turning on anonymous authentication. How shall I go about doing that on the web host server? I dont think I'll have access to that. 
With regard to that endpoint, that is the endpoint generated for me when i added a service reference to the WCF on my localhost.